# Scoped CSS files are not applying their styles in Razor Class Library Components

Tags: html, css, razor, razor-class-library, blazor-component

A component in a Razor Class Library has it's scoped CSS file, but the classes in there are not being applied. Even the CSS class name `my-component` found in the out-of-the-box component `Component1.razor` does not apply to its styles defined in the `Component1.razor.css`

I want to make reusable components to be consumed by a separate Blazor Project. The lack of styling from a scoped CSS file is confusing to me because I was used to scoped CSS files in Blazor Server Apps. What could be the problem? Is there any solution to this?

**`Component1.razor` code**

```
<div class="my-component">
    This component is defined in the <strong>Demo</strong> library.
</div>
```

**`Component1.razor.css` class styles**

```
.my-component {
    border: 2px dashed red;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em 0;
    background-image: url('background.png');
}
```

**Consuming the component**

```
<Component1><Component1/>
```

*The result is just plain text:*
This component is defined in the **Demo** library.

**Provider:**
Razor Class Library targeting `.NET 6.0`

**Consumer:**
Blazor Server App targeting `.NET 6.0`

I hope to get some light on this.